# Single phase 240V generator hooking up to whole house

Tags: electrical, generator

I'm considering a portable generator which provides 240V power to run both 240V and 120V items in the house during an outage, but it says the generator is single phase.  Is this correct for what is needed?

Assume that there's an interlock for safety and that the bonded neutral problem is properly addressed.  Also assume low THD to not damage sensitive items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Residential power in the US is *split-phase* power.  Some people mistakenly think this is the same as "two phase" power, but its not.  We use single phase power of 240v that is split in the middle to also provide 120v circuits.

In commercial settings, three-phase power is a thing, but no one (that I'm aware of) uses true two-phase power so that is almost always a misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks - I think I had some of that misunderstanding on that front so helpful to know.  Does that mean this generator should be good for powering both 120V and 240V in the house (subject to having enough wattage of course)?  The generator has a L14-30R receptacle.  The model is A-iPower SUA6000ED and link to the manual is https://www.powerequipmentdirect.com/manuals/a-ipower-dbb42b744aa067884c35dd2b82a98f6b.pdf in case helpful

Comment: Yes, that connector will provide the same 3-wire split phase power that your appliances expect.  I have seen some small generators that only have 120v outlets, but all the 240v generators I have seen can also power 120v devices.

Comment: Here's a sassy but really good video on how US power works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I appreciate that video having non-automatically-generated subtitles.

Comment: @user I appreciate everything that Technology Connections does.   Browse around, it’s a great channel.  Oil lamp series was great.